# How can I have a popup Google Map appear when the user hovers over an address?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, popup

I want to set up my site so that whenever a user hovers over an address, a small google map of that address pops up. I've been reading through the Google Maps API documentation, but I'm having a hard time finding a simple way to implement this. It seems I have to use what google calls "geocoding" to find the latitude and longitude based on the address... This is the test page I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
          html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
          #map_canvas { height: 100% }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;
            var map;

            function codeAddress(address) {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var myOptions = {
                      zoom: 20,
                      center: results[0].geometry.location,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                    }
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                  } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                  }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div onMouseOver="codeAddress('1405 Harrison Street, Oakland, CA')">
        1405 Harrison Street, Oakland, CA
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This, however, causes the map to show up in the map_canvas div... What I really want is to make the map show up as a little popup, sort of like a tooltip. How can I accomplish this? Also, how can I set it up so that when the user mouses-out, the map disappears?

I'm using html and javascript so far, and my website is in coldfusion.

Answer (score 1):

What you'll want to do is set the `CSS` for your map_canvas div to `display:none`. This way, you'll have complete control over when it's actually shown by using javascript. Once you've done that, it's just a matter of targeting the `hover` event for your mouseover div. You'll probably want to do something like this. First make sure you give your mouseover `div` an `onmouseout` event

```
<div onMouseOver="codeAddress('1405 ...)" onMouseOut="hideMap()" >

</div>
```

Next, target and show the `div` within your `codeAddress` function like so.

```
function codeAddress(address) {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var myOptions = {
                      zoom: 20,
                      center: results[0].geometry.location,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                    }
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                     // here's where you would want to show your map
                     // just use javascript to set the display style to block
                    document.getElementById("map_canvas").style.display = 'block'

                  } else {
                    ... [code here]
                  }
                });
            }
```

Clearly, you'll also want to hide the map upon leaving the div, so your `hideMap` function will do just that.

```
function hideMap(){
 document.getElementById('map_canvas').style.display = 'none'
}
```

I know this doesn't implement your ideal 'tooltip' scenario, however I hope this can get you started. Have a look at [this tooltip library](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html). I've used it before, and it makes it very simple to turn any div into a tooltip. From there, you should be golden. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Style the map_canvas to have a border and look like a separate window.
On the mouseover change the map_canvas(or whatever iframe you want to stick it in) x,y to match the mouseOver x,y.
Set mapcanvas.style.display = "none"; on mouseout

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish a popup-window on mouse over quite easy using some jQuery.

Check out the following jQuery function:

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Idea being that you do something like:

```
<div id="adress1" style="position:relative;">
    72 MacDougal Street, New York, United States
    <div id="map_for_adress1" style="display:none; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">
        <!--GOOGLE MAP, DIV for DATA or EMBED CODE-->
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#adress1").mouseover(function() {

    //When mouse is over...
    $('#map_for_adress1').show(0);

  }).mouseout(function(){

    //When mouse is not over...
    $('#map_for_adress1').hide(0);

  });
</script>
```

Also, why do you need to use the full Google Maps API to show a map of an adress? Why not just the embed-function?

Something like:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=72 MacDougal Street, New York, United States&iwloc=A&output=embed&ie=UTF8"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Banx's solution, I modified the script as follows:

```
(function(){
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
      map = window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.92, -77.06),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }),
      canvas = $("#map_canvas");

  $(".address").hover(function(){
    canvas.css({
      top: $(this).position().top,
      left: $(this).position().left
    }).show();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': $(this).text() }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
      } else {
        // alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }, function(){
    canvas.hide();
  });
})();
```

I used jQuery for handling some DOM stuff there but it should be very easy to change it to whatever library (or not) that you are using. The main difference from Banx's code is it reuses the `map` and `geocoder` objects instead of recreating it every time. Also I am using the `bounds` from the result instead of `location` because it's more desirable in my opinion.